# A permutation group related problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

> If $\tau=(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)(7\ 8)(9\ 10)$ determine whethere there is an $n$ cycle $s$ ($n\ge 10$) with $\tau$=$s^k$ for some integer $k$.

This is a problem of permution group, given in the exercises of Dummit & Foote's book of page 33. Is any kind of generalization of such problem? help me...how i will start?

Comment: Hint: How can you tell that $(123456)^3=(14)(25)(36)$ just by examining the form of the $6$-cycle $(123456)$?

Comment: i th positon number goes to (i+3)(mod 6) for i=0,1,...,5.

Comment: ans relateted to my problem k=5 and s=(13579246810). here the cycle length is 10 and i have to break it into two disjoint cycle.. am i right?@user1

Answer (score 1):

This is true in general for any finite permutation that can be represented as a composition of disjoint $i$-cycles (where $i\in N$ and $1<i$, of course). Say we have a permutation $a$ that can be represented as $\left( a_{0,0} \dots a_{i,0}\right) \dots \left( a_{0,j} \dots  a_{i,j} \right)$ Then $a = \left(a_{0,0} a_{0,1} \dots a_{0,j} a_{1,0} \dots \dots a_{i-1,j-1} a_{0,j} \dots a_{i,j-1} a_{i,j} \right)^j$. This is not true in general for any other sort of finite permutation.